# multiple microphones to audio jack

Tags: microphone

Would it be possible to have two microphones (which simply output a varying voltage between two terminals) connected to an audio jack (i.e. the standard laptop 3.5mm mic jack) and reproduce the sound picked up by both of them?

That is, one would have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXYkra.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Note that a microphone does not only output a signal - if you put a signal across its terminals then it acts as a loudspeaker (and would possibly be destroyed quickly if the signal is large). What kind of microphones are you proposing to use?

Comment: I have not tried this, but, given my EE background, what you described is what I expect. I am proposing using a simple microphone such as https://www.amazon.com/Sony-FV-100-Omnidirectional-Microphone/dp/B000095SAO/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1485810328&sr=8-14&keywords=cheap+microphone

Comment: You could try wiring one microphone to the left input channel and the other to the right and mix them in software. Assuming the laptop in question has a stereo mic input.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, I would like to be able to connect 3 mics if possible.

Comment: This is a dumb question.  Of course it's possible.  What do you expect, that they vanish into a greasy cloud of black smoke or something?  The real question would be whether it achieves your goal.  However, you didn't ask that, nor did you ever state what your goal is!  Closing this disaster of a question.

Comment: Fixed incomplete question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you would not want to direct connect the two microphones as you show in the diagram. Instead it would be better to actually build or purchase a mic mixer box.

A main problem is that many mics these days use a bias from the mic jack to power the sound detection element in the unit. In particular electret mics fall into this category.

Alternatively if your mics are ones that produce an output signal voltage without a bias then you could consider the very simplest mic mixer. This would be a resistor in series with each mic output into the mic jack input with a third resistor to the low side of the mic jack connection.

[image]

This type of resistor pad mixer does have the issue that it reduces the overall signal into the amplifier from each mic. This is one reason that most mic mixers as recommended above have a gain circuit for each mic input.